# Angular promise failure on timeout

Tags: angularjs, timeout, angular-promise

I want my promise to fail if it fails to return a result within 300ms, in case of failure I want another promise to be called which would be executing a default function which has a smaller execution time.

What I've tried so far -

```
    $timeout(function(){
      GetAirMsg.get({mDate: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'ddMMyy'),
                mDateO: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'yyyyMMdd'),
                mDateD: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
                acode: $filter('uppercase')($scope.air),
                offset: offsetInt}).$promise.then(function(result){
                /* result evaluation */    
            });
      },300).then(function(data){

         console.log('Timed out! sorry!');
         /*execute another promise with shorter execution time */
         console.log('data : '+data);

      },function(error){

        //console.log('Timed out! sorry!');

    });
```

and the service is -

```
angular.module('example').factory('GetAirMsg',['$resource',function($resource){
return $resource(serverBaseUrl + '/getAirMsg/:mDate/:mDateO/:mDateD/:acode/:offset', 
        {mDate: '@mDate',mDateO: '@mDateO',mDateD: '@mDateD',acode: '@acode',offset: '@offset'}, {
            get: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
        });
}])
```

The service GetAirMsg executes a query which takes up a lot of time for a few values, the query is as optimized as it can at the moment. So I would like a fallback to be available which returns only the basic information.

Problem faced now - The console always shows 
'Timed out! sorry!
data : undefined'. The request remains in the pending state for cases which don't return a value within that timeframe.

Comment: If you want to execute another Promise on fail. Use `.catch()` after that `.then()`. and not on the `(err)` of after `.then()`.

Comment: @ReyanTropia how do I make my promise fail if it fails to return a result within 300 ms , because right now the call remains in the pending state in my network ? I'm new to angular and I'm not sure how to go about doing this. TIA :)

Comment: this is odd. your request status is still `pending`? Then that .then(data) should'nt fire at all. Btw `Promises` are not cancellable. Only `Observables` can be cancelled.

Comment: @ReyanTropia Right now the console.log message is displayed regardless of the state of the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `timeout` setting of `$resource`. See a sample usage [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kursadgulseven/bzoxksty/).

As an example for your code;

Service:

```
angular.module('example').factory('GetAirMsg',['$resource',function($resource){
return $resource(serverBaseUrl + '/getAirMsg/:mDate/:mDateO/:mDateD/:acode/:offset', 
        {mDate: '@mDate',mDateO: '@mDateO',mDateD: '@mDateD',acode: '@acode',offset: '@offset'}, {
            get: {method: 'GET', isArray: false, timeout: 300}
        });
}])
```

Controller:

```
GetAirMsg.get({mDate: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'ddMMyy'),
        mDateO: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'yyyyMMdd'),
        mDateD: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
        acode: $filter('uppercase')($scope.air),
        offset: offsetInt}).$promise
    .then(function(result){
        /* result evaluation */    
    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log("error!");
    });
```

Comment: This causes the request status to turn to canceled in case of timeout but my query is still running , this causes other requests to remain pending and my application is crashing

Comment: This issue is not relevant to your question. It's about your REST API. You can set timeout for your REST requests (server-side) or set your REST API to allow cancelation by calling a special REST method. Which language/system are you using for your REST API?

Comment: I'm figuring out a way set a timer on the backend for my project. We are using organisation specific packages so I'm trying to figure that out. I'm using python for backend. Thank you for your quick response. Your solution works great.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for showing that console is because the `timeout` function worked successfully and since `timeout` not returning any data, the `data` will be `undefined`

try this.

**controller code:**

```js
$scope.isFirstCallSuccess = false;

$timeout(function(){
 GetAirMsg.get({
  mDate: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'ddMMyy'),
  mDateO: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'yyyyMMdd'),
  mDateD: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
  acode: $filter('uppercase')($scope.air),
  offset: offsetInt})
  .$promise
  .then(function(result){
  /* result evaluation */    
  $scope.isFirstCallSuccess = true; // updating only if call success
 }, ,function(error){
  // API call was failure even before the timeout
 });
},300).then(function(){
 if(!$scope.isFirstCallSuccess){
  //the call was failure. the value is still false
  /*execute another promise with shorter execution time */
  console.log('Timed out! sorry!');
 }

});
```

**EDIT:**

Method: create one more service to cancel promises. Use that service to cancel if it's not completed before timeout ends

**service:**

```
function cancel( promise ) {
//it will cancel the promise only the promise is still active
  if (promise) {
    promise.reject();
  }
}
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.gettingAirMsg = GetAirMsg.get({
    mDate: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'ddMMyy'),
    mDateO: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'yyyyMMdd'),
    mDateD: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
    acode: $filter('uppercase')($scope.air),
    offset: offsetInt})
    .$promise
    .then(function(result){
        //success
        }, ,function(error){

    });

 $timeout(function(){
   yourService.cancel($scope.gettingAirMsg) 
   //it will cancel the promise only the promise is still active
   // if the promise ends before 300ms the cancel call will not pass active promise
 },300)
```

Comment: Doesn't really work for me - the promises which are successful in returning values within 300ms work well, but for those which don't, the request call is still pending because of which my network gets clogged and my application crashes. So basically the promises fail to return 'failure' in case of a timeout. I'm probably missing something I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Updated the answer. Check now

Comment: Cool :) You can use `reject()` or `resole()`. Both will work.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for showing that console is because the `timeout` function worked successfully and since `timeout` not returning any data, the `data` will be `undefined`

try this.

**controller code:**

```js
$scope.isFirstCallSuccess = false;

$timeout(function(){
  GetAirMsg.get({
      mDate: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'ddMMyy'),
      mDateO: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'yyyyMMdd'),
      mDateD: $filter('date')($scope.realdateFrom,'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
      acode: $filter('uppercase')($scope.air),
      offset: offsetInt})
    .$promise
    .then(function(result){
    /* result evaluation */    
    $scope.isFirstCallSuccess = true; // updating only if call success
  },function(error){
    // API call was failure even before the timeout
  });
  },300).then(function(){
  if(!$scope.isFirstCallSuccess){
    //the call was failure. the value is still false
    /*execute another promise with shorter execution time */
    console.log('Timed out! sorry!');
  }

});
```